# Mysql query with inner subquery and where,order,group not use indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, database-indexes, filesort

all.
I have 2 mysql tables type myisam

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users_ratings` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating1` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating2` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Dump can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LDFMVGJQZfOWpnWjNqNkhfM2s/view?usp=sharing)

I want all users to select and sort the list by rating2 and rating2 must be > 1000

```
SELECT * FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT rating2, user_id,MAX(created_date) as maxdate FROM `users_ratings` GROUP BY user_id) as x ON x.user_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN users_ratings as ur ON(ur.created_date = x.maxdate and ur.user_id = u.id) 
WHERE x.rating2 > 1000 
ORDER by ur.rating2
```

Without such an index the query is executed for 9 seconds.

All possible codes, which I thought was allowed to reduce the time of the request to 1-2 seconds.

Help the right to place indexes

Comment: In general, in aggregating queries, if you SELECT an unaggregated column then you also need to include it in your GROUP BY clause. MySQL forgives the omission (other RDBMSs do not) but can lead to unpredictable and confusing results.

Comment: sqlfiddle is better setup for people to see than download from google drive

Comment: Your question is unclear.  For instance, what does `created_date` have to do with anything?  Would the maximum rating suffice?

Comment: I want to get users with its latest (max (created_date)) rating1 and rating2. The database is kept dynamic changes in the ratings of users.

Comment: @Drew Пока что не имею опыта рыботы с sqlfiddle, но в будущем научусь, спасибо!

Comment: удачи мой друг. дайте нам знать

Comment: @Drew I tried to dump their sqlfiddle and received an error [Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/46587c6b45196c9920be55568119f069.png) Apparently I was not lucky

Comment: Почему мы вдруг говорит по-русски

Comment: @Strawberry obviously, because I'm Russian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want the following query. Assuming you do, and performance is still an issue, provide the EXPLAIN for same...

(this assumes a Unique Key on `user_id,[rating2,]created_date`, which hasn't actually been specified)

```
SELECT u.*
     , x.*
  FROM users u 
  JOIN users_ratings x
    ON x.user_id = u.id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , MAX(created_date) maxdate 
         FROM users_ratings
        WHERE rating2 > 1000
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.maxdate = x.created_date
 ORDER 
    BY x.rating2;
```

Comment: I tried to make a unique index as you advised, the result of a query on the basis of the test is very pleased. Thanks. I will understand what were my mistakes.
[Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/afd2c4f048b87a8192cabf8a31557cd8.png)

Comment: Real time performance
[Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/49450bf00355ee4e43972109246e5b9b.png)

Comment: increased number of entries in the tables users_ratings(186к) and users(76k) This query is executed 700ms. Still in search of solutions. It is expected about 2 million records in users